# How can I detect double click events in matplotlib?

Tags: python, events, double-click, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
    print event.button

fig = plt.figure()
connection_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

With a construct like this, I have the problem of double-clicks hitting `onclick()` handler *three* times.  I guess that it is receiving both the clicks, and an additional double-click event.  How can I change this behaviour so that the event handler is not fired for double-click events?  Or, alternatively, how can I detect them from the event instance so that I can ignore those double-clicks?

*note:  `button_release_event` does not have this problem, but I want to fire on the `button_press_event`*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When i had matplotlib version 1.1rc, i was not able to catch dblclick event.
Later, I wrote code  for matplotlib 1.2 and that is ok

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick:
         print event.button

connection_id = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, this is a better solution than mine so I will change the accepted answer :)

Comment: Note that the `event.dblclick` attribute is *not* active for `'button_release_event'`, only for `'button_press_event'`. Or at least, I was unable to get it working with release events.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to detect the case by using

`from gtk.gdk import BUTTON_PRESS, _2BUTTON_PRESS. _3BUTTON_PRESS`

***note:*** the reason for underscores on double and triple click enum types is not that they are _protected, but to dodge the issue where you aren't allowed to have an attribute starting with a number.  You can check the event type with:

`event.guiEvent.type`

However, I later found out that the import will cause an exception if you are using a different backend (moreover, I only have this problem with 'GTKAgg' backend).  So now I use a construct like this:

```
from gtk.gdk import BUTTON_PRESS as singleclick

if plt.get_backend() == 'GTKAgg':
    if hasattr(event, 'guiEvent') and event.guiEvent.type != singleclick:
        # suppress double click event
        return
```

If anyone has a cleaner solution, feel free to add it here.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problem when I was using matplotlib 1.1.
There was no 'dblclick' event type. So I implemented it by myself. I required the time interval between two clicks must be smaller than 0.5 sec or the program would do nothing. User could tune this setting by itself according to its experience.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig = plt.figure()
one_click_trigger = False
time_first_click  = 0

def mouseDoubleClick(event):
    global one_click_trigger
    global time_first_click

    if one_click_trigger == False:
        one_click_trigger = True
        time_first_click = time.time()
        return
    else:
        double_click_interval = time.time() - time_first_click
        if double_click_interval > 0.5:
            one_click_trigger = False
            time_first_click = 0
            return

    print "Double click!"

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', mouseDoubleClick)
plt.show()
```