# Distinguish between single and double click with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent, double-click

I'm trying to catch single clicks and double clicks on my figure.

As stated in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753195/4537483), the `event` contains `event.dblclick` which is False or True, at least in Version 1.4.2, so double clicks can be got.

The only problem is that it's not easy to distinguish between a single click and a double click because when double-clicking the event gets fired twice. The first time it's with `event.dblclick=False` and the second time it's with `event.dblclick=True`.

Is there any solution to this? I saw that the same problem regarding qt is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627347/distinguish-between-single-and-double-click-events-in-qt).

Answer (score 3):

You need a software debouncer.

Basically, you start a timer on the 1st click. If the timer runs out, then you proceed to process the single-click event. If a 2nd click is detected within the timer, process a double-click event.

This can actually be expanded to n-clicks if needed. I've found some uses for triple-click events.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992288/1354930) is one implemented in wxPython. Should be relatively easy to port to matplotlib.

---

Also, if you're on Windows, I would recommend using the user's double-click speed for your timer (Control Panel: Mouse). You can access it with:

```
get_double_click_time():
    """ Gets the Windows double click time in ms """
    from ctypes import windll
    return int(windll.user32.GetDoubleClickTime())
```

I haven't yet figured out how to grab the dclick time from Mac or Linux (but I also don't have a need to).