# Python pyplot: Handling double-click event catches also the first click event

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I wrote a code that handles different events for both - mouse single-click and double click.
The problem is that each time that user double-click the mouse it triggers also single-click and after that trigger the double-click event.

I want that double-click will trigger only one event!! the double-click event.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe post the code that you have written (possibly as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: Hi Thomas, my code is bit long and I think it will not contribute.. the idea is that I have two different functions - one for single click and one for double click and I want that double-click will trigger only the double click function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinguish between single and double click with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416662/distinguish-between-single-and-double-click-with-matplotlib)

Comment: I saw it, no answer there...
The idea is clear but how to implement it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As linked by @ThomasKühn, the answer is to create a software debounce. There are several ways to go about it, and the solution probably depends on your application (are you using a GUI, what backend, etc.) To be as agnostic as possible, I've implemented my solution using a one-shot thread [from the threading module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects).

```
import threading
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DEBOUNCE_DUR = 0.25
t = None


def on_press(event):
    global t
    if t is None:
        t = threading.Timer(DEBOUNCE_DUR, on_singleclick, [event])
        t.start()
    if event.dblclick:
        t.cancel()
        on_dblclick(event)


def on_dblclick(event):
    global t
    print("You double-clicked", event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    t = None


def on_singleclick(event):
    global t
    print("You single-clicked", event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata)
    t = None


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! looks as the solution I have looked for!

Comment: since Matplotlib is not thread save, this doesnt work for me. It registers the doubleclick, but afterwards it only can register doubleclicks

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking for a solution for a embedded Matplotlib canvas in Tkinter, I came up for another solution (since the accepted answer doesn't work quite well in that case) here is a codesnipped which will hopefully help others struggling with tkinter and matplotlib:

```
def _on_click_debounce(self,event):
    if self._job is None:
        self._job = root.after(self.DEBOUNCE_DUR, lambda: self._on_click(event))
    if event.dblclick:
        root.after_cancel(self._job)
        self._job = None
        self._on_dblclick(event)

def _on_dblclick(self,event):
    print('dblclick!')

def _on_click(self,event):
    print('singleclick!')
    self._job = None
```

The function `_on_click_debounce` gets handed over to the matplotlib eventhandling (`fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', _on_click_debounce)`) and root is just the global `root = tkinter.Tk()` of tkinter